# Problem parsing some JSON from php to android

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to parse in android some json that a web service (in PHP) echo.

This is the code of the parsing:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            pDialog.hide();

            //CAMBIAR A NUMERO
            String turno = "nada";

            JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("turnoSacado");
            JSONObject jsonObject=null;

            try {
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
                turno = jsonObject.getString("turnoActual");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Hola: ", "estas entrando por aca");
            }

            turnoSacado.setText(turno);//SE MODIFICA}
```

and I get this error:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value el of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

If anyone can give me some help ill appreciate.

Comment: Can you post your json format? It seems that your `json.getJSONObject(0)` is not `JSONObject` and you need replace `json.getJSONObject(0)` to `json.getString(0)` and replace type `jsonObject` from `JSONObject` to `String`.

Comment: Santiago, post the structure of your json string just so people would be able to help you. It would be very difficult to help not knowing any details.